# Testing if a value is numeric

Tags: python, regex, testing

How can we write a test that checks if a value is numeric, and throw an exception is the value is not numeric? Do we need regular expressions in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: No you don't, you can test the type with `isinstance()` function.

Comment: If you want an exception thrown why even bother testing?

Comment: @PM2Ring they want to throw an exception only if the value is not numeric.

Comment: @user118967 Sure, but the simple way to do that is to assume the value *is* numeric, and let Python raise ValueError if it isn't, as shown in the 1st code block of umläute's answer. See https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-eafp

Comment: I see, @PM2Ring. EAFP is an interesting principle. Personally I find that sometimes we want to check and raise an exception with a more clear message. For example, it may be a better error message to say "Age must be a number but received: 'fifty'" than something like "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'". The former will help a user correct the erroneous input, especially if they are just a user and not a developer looking at the code.

Comment: @user118967 Certainly, and that's what you *should* do, in an `except` clause. Users should *never* see a raw Traceback. But the OP said they wanted to throw an exception. Perhaps they intended to catch that exception somewhere...

Answer (score 13):

You can use the numbers module.

```
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(1, numbers.Number)
True
>>> isinstance('a', numbers.Number)
False
```

It should be noted that complex numbers are considered part of numbers.Number as well, if you only want real numbers you can do:

```
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(1, numbers.Real)
True
>>> isinstance(1j, numbers.Real)
False
```

As far as throwing an exception if a value is not numeric I would just do:

```
assert isinstance(my_value, numbers.Real)
```

Which will throw `AssertionError` if `my_value` is not a real number.

Comment: Will also work for ```decimal.Decimal```. ```import decimal; isinstance(decimal.Decimal(1.3), numbers.Number)``` is ```True```.

Answer (score 5):

There are three distinct number types in Python 3 (int, float and complex). Note that boolean is a subclass of int.

You can check for them as follows:

```
def check_numeric(x):
    if not isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)):
        raise ValueError('{0} is not numeric'.format(x))
```

The function does nothing if the parameter is numeric.  If it is not, it throws a ValueError.

```
>>> check_numeric(1)

>>> check_numeric(True)

>>> check_numeric(1.5)

>>> check_numeric(10L)

>>> check_numeric(complex(1, 2))

>>> check_numeric('spam')
ValueError: spam is not numeric
```

Comment: The use of the `any()` built in function would probably be a good idea here.

Comment: You can pass a tuple of types as the 2nd arg of [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: And `long` is no longer a type in python 3. Updated response accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

if your "numeric values" are actually strings, then easiest way is certainly to just run a test-conversion.

e.g. if you expect a floating-point value, convert to `float`)

```
  def is_float(v):
      f=float(v)
      return True

  >>> is_float(2.2)
  True
  >>> is_float("3.14")
  True
  >>> is_float("ouch")
  ValueError: could not convert string to float: ouch
```

note: if you just want to raise an exception, then you probably don't need a wrapper function `is_float()`. just do the assignment directly...

if you don't necessarily want to raise an exception, but just test for numeric-ness, a more consistent implementation of `is_float()` would catch the error and return `False`:

```
  def is_float(v):
      try:
        f=float(v)
      except ValueError:
        return False
      return True
```

Comment: If you're going to write a function named `is_float` (camel case should only be used for class names, not function names), you should catch the exception and return False.

Comment: @chepner, thx, changed the function name to `is_float()`; I did not return `False`, as the OP explicitely asked for an exception to be thrown; in any case, I added your suggestion to the answer